# TFS Administration Console Adding and Removing Users

Tags: tfs

I am working with team foundation server and I added a user in the server from Administration Console and the user has access to the server. But the problem is even when I remove that user from Administration Console user still able to login to the server. Can anyone help me here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "login to the server"? The admin console is for administrative tasks and administrative users. If a user is a member of **any** TFS group, they will have access to TFS. Admin console users and server admin groups do not represent the only place where a user can be granted access.

Comment: @DanielMann agreed that is what I thought. so I create a group there add that group to the server but none of the user of that group able to login to the server. Then I add one user from that group using the administrative console that user able to login, and now I removed that user from console but he still able to login. any suggesstions? Is there somthing wrong with the installation of TFS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove users completely from TFS server. You should **remove the user from all the security groups**.

UsE the command below to get this account has been added to which groups. Then check all those groups and try to remove that account from those groups.

*[TFS security imx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd?view=azure-devops#imx-display-information-about-the-identities-that-the-expanded-membership):*

```
tfssecurity /imx [domain\account] /server:[server url]
```

Besides, changes you make to local or Active Directory groups **do not get reflected in TFS immediately.** Instead, TFS will synchronize those groups regularly.

A periodic clean-up job that is executed removes people from the global groups. If you just wait, they will disappear in a couple of days. They will not have access to any of the TFS assets however.

You could look in http://tfs.mydomain.com:8080/tfs/_oi  to see the sync job.

If you cannot wait for the scheduled job, you can try to do the force sync: http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory.aspx

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT i think you are right these changes are not reflected immediately, thats the reason for my issue. Thank you for the command.